# How to capture Y coordinates with touchmove?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a mobile application with html, javascript with canvas, basically scrolling down increases the zoom of an image and scrolling up decreases the zoom of the image, but I can only decrease the zoom because when doing scroll up keeps increasing the size and i want it to decrease the size.

Part of the javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event)=>{

  if (event.pageY < 0) {
    zoomLevel /= 1.1; // zoom out by 10%
  } else if (event.pageY > 0) {
    zoomLevel *= 1.1; // zoom in by 10%
  }

  if (zoomLevel < 1) {
    zoomLevel = 1;
  } else if (zoomLevel > 5) {
    zoomLevel = 5;
  }
  drawImage();

})


function drawImage() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // draw zoom area
  const imgWidth = img.width * zoomLevel;
  const imgHeight = img.height * zoomLevel;
  const imgX = canvasWidth / 2 - imgWidth / 2;
  const imgY = canvasHeight / 2 - imgHeight / 2;
  ctx.drawImage(img, imgX, imgY, imgWidth, imgHeight);

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `touchmove` instead of `scroll` events? The problem with your code is that it can only zoom in. `pageY` just tells you the vertical position on the page the event occurred, and the vertical position is *always* greater than 0

Comment: I use touchmove because it works for cell phones and I also use the "wheel" event (I use it for computers) it works correctly when decreasing the zoom (scroll up), also I did not mention that the image is fixed, that is, it does not have the bars of scroll, for this reason the "scroll" event does not work for cell phones

Comment: Even then, you could just add a scroll to your page even though your image is fixed and base it on that. Otherwise you will have to store the client position of the touch and calculate the delta, giving you a negative value when scrolling up.

Comment: @somethinghere I solved it by storing the position of the touch as said. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `Delta Y` solve it with the following code, which stores the touch position.

```js
let zoomLevel = 1;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
  y = event.touches[0].clientY;
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
  const deltaY = event.touches[0].clientY - y;
  y = event.touches[0].clientY;

  zoomLevel = Math.min(5, Math.max(1, zoomLevel + deltaY * 0.01));
  drawImage();
});
```